# java.lang.OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: android, bitmap

Getting **java.lang.OutOfMemory** Exception -- Bitmap

I know **inSampleSize** will help me to resolve my issue, but little bit confuse how it has to be use in my code.

**Exception line:-**

```
bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBM, 0, 0, tempBM.getWidth(),
```

**showPicture() method:**

```
private void showPicture(){
        if(pic!=null) tempBM = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic);
        Bitmap bMapRotate;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if(info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
            Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
            matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);
            matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
            bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBM, 0, 0, tempBM.getWidth(),
            tempBM.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        }

        if(Utility.isTablet(this)) {
             int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

            if(orient==1){
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBM, 0,0,tempBM.getWidth(),
                tempBM.getHeight(), matrix ,true);
                tempBM = bMapRotate;
            }

        }else{
            //Get Orientation:
            int orientation;

            if(tempBM.getHeight() < tempBM.getWidth()){
                orientation = 90;
            } else {
                orientation = 0;
            }
            if (orientation != 0) {
                matrix.postRotate(orientation);
                bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBM, 0, 0, tempBM.getWidth(),
                        tempBM.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            } else
                bMapRotate = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBM, tempBM.getWidth(),
                        tempBM.getHeight(), true);

            tempBM = bMapRotate;
        }
```

Log:-

```
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at com.tanukiteam.camera.CameraAPIActivity.showPicture(CameraAPIActivity.java:685)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at com.tanukiteam.camera.CameraAPIActivity.access$1(CameraAPIActivity.java:650)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at com.tanukiteam.camera.CameraAPIActivity$1.onPictureTaken(CameraAPIActivity.java:539)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:789)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
01-29 10:16:04.625: E/AndroidRuntime(20234):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please provide some code  , and the full stack trace

Comment: @Amrola please check now

Comment: please tell me what code is at line 685 in CameraAPIActivity.java

Comment: my guess is: `Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBM, 0,0,tempBM.getWidth(),`

Comment: @Amrola yeah gian1200 is right i highlighted above

Comment: check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/957654

Comment: where u r showing image in listview?

Comment: thats is becoz u r using some imageview for very first time and puting on that imageview again and again so memory out of error accours ...on resultok of camera try to put claear the variables first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bitmaps` take up lots of memory, especially big ones. You most likely need to scale the `Bitmap` down before loading it into memory. [This tutorial](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/05/solving-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget.html) is a good example of how to go about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your `tempBM` is too large to store in memory. You can use `BitmapFactory.Options` when decoding your resource file to make your bitmap smaller. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

Comment: @suitanshi can you show me by making changes in my existing code

Comment: @AbrahimNeil. There's already a training class about using `inSampleSize`, refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). You can simply copy some code to your project. It's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First stop your application from crashing at run time by catching the OutOfMemory error at place which you think can generate this error as below:

```
try {

...

}
catch(OutOfMemoryError error)  {
    //decide what to do when there is not more memory available
}
```

(OR)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Calling Garbage Collector is a good Idea.

Comment: we should not rely on `gc`. The ideal solution should be scaling `tempBM` down